# Отображение графического интерфейса в ОС без графической оболочки

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ui

Возник вопрос как можно ли создать графический интерфейс для приложения в ОС без UI, например в Linux Ubuntu Server16.04 или чистом Linux ядре. У нас есть только терминал и все, и запуская приложение оно может отображать и получать данные только через терминал. Но есть ли путь для создания графического интерфейса в таком случае?

Конечно можно создать веб сервер и графическое отображение будет в "веб-морде", но как это сделать непосредственно на устройстве?

Как это реализуют в устройствах работающих под управлением Linux, например IP видеорегистратор и тому подобное

Comment: Нативный вариант отрисовки "графических" программ с машин без графической морды — запуск на клиентской машине X-сервера. На юниксах он часто уже запущен, на вёндах надо запустить eXceed или Xming и затем запускать нужную программу в ssh-сессии с форвардингом X-трафика (ssh -X -C с юниксов или соответствующие галки в настройках putty на windows). Можно попробовать через SDL, но тут не знаю конкретики. А вообще, вы спрашиваете "можно ли сделать GUI без GUI?". Можно ли узнать, зачем, если можно сделать GUI с GUI?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, просто у меня встал вопрос как на одноплатном компьютере, работающем на Linux или Android, отрисовать на подключено дисплее приложение... То есть включаешь устроим во и сразу загружается приложение с графическим интерфейсом. Не могу найти как это реализуется, буду очень признателен ессэли Вы направит меня на путь истиный

Comment: Я бы попробовал как в ответе @eri — запускать нужное приложение при старте X-сервера. То есть X и сразу на нём - программа. Без DE, без WM, воще без ничего. Читать в сторону xinit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На IP видеорегистраторе есть X-сервер, на более дорогих и на более старых графика работает через framebuffer.

Для начала нового проекта в этой теме рекомендую QT https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html

Если в устройстве есть поддержка opengl, то запускай на EGLFS. Если нет видеоядра, то LinuxFB.

PySide2 и PyQt5 поддерживают эти режимы.

Заработает сразу

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb python3 hellopyqt.py
```

С eglfs похоже надо скомпилировать отдельную версию Qt, это один-два дня... https://github.com/fhunleth/qt-rectangles#compiling-the-eglfs-version-of-qt-5

Системная версия у меня не видит экрана и зависает. возможно это изза драйверов nvidia, возможно поддержка платформы не собрана. 2 года назад делал - надо вспоминать и написать статью по этому случаю.

Если в программировании не силен, или надо вывести вэб приложение, то самый простой способ - это запустить хром в режиме киоска на голых иксах.

Вот сейчас попробовал на ASROCK D1800M. Debian 10 minimal.

```
apt install python3-pyqt5

QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs python3 hellopyqt.py
```

И всё заработало. Компилить qt не надо.

Comment: А можете подсказать какую либо литературу по теме EGLFS.и реализации такого приложения при помощи PyQT5?

Comment: EGLFS - это просто отрисовщик окон qt напрямую в opengl просто запускаете с параметрами и поехали

Comment: С нетерпением буду ждать ссылку на Вашу статью, если напишите все же)

Comment: жду киоск 40" - туда планировался QML интерфейс на eglfs, должны были в марте прислать) на 17" киосках (киви) делал qml поверх иксов потому как не получилось откалибровать тач без xinput

Comment: А можете подсказать где мне найти "QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG" и как его править? Проблемы с курсором мыши говорят надо изменить конфиг "hwcursor" : false а вот где его искать то никто не сказал)

Comment: И вообще при повторной попытке запуска приложения по ssh выдает ошибку >> Failed to move cursor on screen Virtual1: -13
Running on a software rasterizer (LLVMpipe), expect limited performance.

Comment: The KMS/DRM backend also supports custom configurations via a JSON file. To enable this, set the QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG environment variable to the name of the file.

Comment: QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG создаешь свой и через эту переменную его указываешь. ещё рендер LLVMpipe - говорит что у вас нет драйвера на видео.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего использовать какую-либо библиотеку для TUI или псевдографики. Если очень сойти с ума, то можно перевести устройство вывода в графический режим и рисовать на нём всё, что душе угодно, включая окна.